# Form Authenticity Token getting changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4, I'm using the normal `form_for` helper which renders a hidden element which stores `form_authenticity_token` value.

Now when I do the `POST` request I get the `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error. These are my request parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"euVcp8lEVyg3JZVZeMGI0G2SV4y8Jukmz9GUv6ZO34I=",     "confirmation_token"=>"jLdtGNf5fWnDiEjV5xDU", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Activate"}
```

My `application.html.erb` also contains `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

So, I put the debugger inside source code and found out that, the value of `form_authenticity_token` is now changed to something else it's not same as the `authenticity_token`'s value in the request parameter & hence the `verify_authenticity_token` raises an error.

I don't know why this value is being changed.

### Update

```
def form_authenticity_token
  session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
end
```

First when I try to print `session` I get

```
#<Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash:0x15cb970 not yet loaded>
```

and then I force load by doing `session[:a] = :b`

and then I found out the value of `session[:_csrf_token]` is `nil` & Hence the value is changed because a new random value is generated which doesn't match with my form value.

Now I need to find out why it is `nil`

Comment: Is the post request coming form javascript/ajax?

Comment: Nope, plain old rails way

Comment: I just updated the question with new information

Comment: @Anthony Found the issue in case you might be interested

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain Why are you changing the value of the authenticity token? I assume you're keeping it in the form as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
```

It is possible that your ||= is changing the value. I think a little more information on what you're trying to do would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm not changing it, the method is from the rails source code. Yes, the authenticity token is in the hidden field it was generated by rails by the way I found out the solution

Answer (score 0):

Might help to anyone in the future, Here's why I had the problem, I had the following code

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                       key: '_foo_session',
                                       domain: '.example.com'
```

inside my `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, I added a while ago the `domain:` key to use custom domain instead of `localhost` & completely forgot about it.

Now, with this configuration I was trying to do a `POST` request by loading the application at `localhost:3000` instead of `example.com:3000`, Hence the session's `_csrf_token` was `nil`.

When I did the `POST` request by actually visiting the app on `example.com:3000` it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem as well, but we noticed that it happened only when using http:// and worked ok on https://. So we forced our app to use HTTPS :)

Cause: session_store had `secure: true` like this

```
Rails.application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store,
  key: '_foo_session',
  domain: '.example.com',
  secure: true
)
```

which resulted in non-secure requests having no session/token.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this issue in Rails 7 caused by a form embedded in another form. For instance, you may have:

```
<%= form_for ... %>
    <%= form_for ... %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But you meant to have:

```
<%= form_for ... %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for ... %>
<% end %>
```